# Sharing a global javascript object across frames

Tags: javascript, html, iframe

This may sound ridiculous but there are some situations when we need to share `JavaScript Objects` across `iframe`.

When we try to use `localStorage` for serving the purpose, people say that some browsers might not support it.Even if they support localStorage, Users might've reduced the storage capacity and so forth...
So my question is, Do we have a Solution/Alternative to share `JavaScript` Objects across `iframe`
Below example might get us on the same page

**parentpage.html**

```
<html>
...
<head><script src="script1.js" type="text/Javascript"></script></head>
<body>
...
<iframe src="childpage.html"></iframe>
</body>
</html>
```

**childpage.html**

```
<html>
...
<head><script src="script2.js" type="text/Javascript"></script></head>
...
</html>
```

**note**:
*parentpage.html , childpage.html, script1.js, script2.js* reside in the same domain and in the same location

Assume that script1.js uses a `JavaScript Object` that needs to be made publicly available.

Since the browser/UserAgent creates a separate `Window Object` for each additional `iframe` used in the page and we can't access the `Public JavaScript Object` if we attach/Extend it to the `Window Object/Document Object`, The Last hope of it seems to fade away!

Is there any Solution/Workaround?

Comment: Put the object on the top-most page. Child frames can then refer to `top.globalObject` to access it.

Comment: Thanks man! This might work. since the child page `iframe` is inside the main page, it sounds reasonable to use `top` as our interface of communication. But I haven't tried it yet! I'll try it to make sure it works fine

Comment: It should work fine so long as all your pages really are from the same domain. I've worked on a large project that made extensive use of that for inter-frame coordination; it's worked fine in browsers dating way way back.

Comment: @Pointy It works! Thanks a bunch. So as you said `window.top` Property/Member/Object of a page from **domain1** is not accessible to a page from **domain2** . That I need to check it out!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As @Pointy Suggested, the best Alternative to `LocalStoage` for sharing data across frames is to use `window.top` Property/Member/Object

But still, the Property is **ReadOnly** as mentioned in mozilla dev docs but I still wonder if it's not in anyway forced strictly in the future not to add new Member/Field to `window.top`

Refer: [Mozilla Dev Docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/window.top)

Answer (score 1):

Sharing data across multiple iframes that belongs to multiple domains can be done through postMessage

Comment: as you can see from the markup and the note it's all on the same domain, so no need for that.